# When use post, when use get

Tags: node.js, json, api, http

I have a doubt, I have an API in which I will pass a JSON to get data referring to a request.

So is it necessary to use the ResquestBody, in this case, do I use GET or POST?

Comment: You should not send data with GET, so you need to use POST, PUT or PATCH, depending on the action. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass a request body, you cannot use GET.

So, use POST, PUT, or PATCH.

Plus, GET parameters go into web server logs because they're part of URLs. So never use GET parameters for secrets. That is, always use POST for things like password updates.